# Flutter/Dart - Why would onPressed on my iconButton work

Tags: flutter, function, dart, flutter-onpressed

I have the following IconButton in Flutter which when `onPressed`, triggers an audioplayer to play;

```
  IconButton(
          key: const Key('play_button'),
          onPressed: _play,
          iconSize: 30,
          icon: Icon(PlayerButtons.playbuttonbig),
        ),
```

But why would it fail to play when I do this instead?

```
  IconButton(
          key: const Key('play_button'),
          onPressed:(){
            _play;
          },
          iconSize: 30,
          icon: Icon(PlayerButtons.playbuttonbig),
        ),
```

The reason I need to use the 2nd is because I want to call another function before or after "_play"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IconButton(
          key: const Key('play_button'),
          onPressed:(){
            _play(); //<- call the play function like this
          }, 
          iconSize: 30,
          icon: Icon(PlayerButtons.playbuttonbig),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IconButton(
      key: const Key('play_button'),
      onPressed:(){
        _play();
      },
      iconSize: 30,
      icon: Icon(PlayerButtons.playbuttonbig),
    ),
```

if _play() is a function this should work